# Hard coded string to be made to bold

Tags: string, vb.net

complete code is as below I am fetching the value and sending it in mail but value hard coded ISMS: need to be in bold.

```
Public Function CCC_GetISMS_Details( ByVal dbPwOHelperPwO As ISingleDbObject) As String
    
    Dim scriptErrorBase As String = "Script Error [CCC_GetISMS_Details]"
    Dim fkPwo As IForeignKey = dbPwOHelperPwO.GetFK("UID_PersonWantsOrg")
    Dim orderDetail2 As String = String.Empty
    Dim DetailStrg As New StringBuilder
        
    'there is a related pwo
    If Not fkPwo.IsEmpty Then
        
        Dim pwo As ISingleDbObject = fkPwo.Create()
        'orderDetail2 = pwo.GetValue("OrderDetail2").String
        'User Story 9672 to fetch the right ISMS Group from request and send it in approval mail
        orderDetail2 = pwo.ObjectWalker.GetValue("FK(CCC_UID_CSMGroup).GroupName")
        
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(orderDetail2) Then
            DetailStrg.AppendLine(String.Format("ISMS: {0}",orderDetail2))
        End If  
        
    Else
        Throw New Exception(scriptErrorBase & " no related person want org record!")
    End If

    Return DetailStrg.ToString()

End Function
```

Comment: Where is the string being displayed? An HTML document, in a richtext box, a PDF, or...?

Comment: Hi Andrew , It is HTML document

Answer (score 0):

```
DetailStrg.AppendLine($"<b>ISMS:</b> {orderDetail2}")
```